# JSF - checking null and empty in single method

Tags: java, jsf

Currently my code is like

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.allSelectedMedicationList != null && !empty templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.allSelectedMedicationList}">
        <b>List of Selected Drugs</b> // and some other stuff
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now `allSelectedMedicationList` will do lot of process in backend. Calling webservice and adding data in current DB and so on...

Now issue arise when I need to check `null` or `empty` - **2 times** that method called here. Once again when I use same method with datatable it will call again **1 more** time. 
I think to create one method or something for JSF it self that will check `null` and `empty` at same time and return list. **Is it possible?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator "empty" already does what you want, you don't need to also check null.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaik:

*Empty: The empty operator is a prefix operation that can be used to determine whether a value is null or empty.*

Comment: Thanks... That documentation is for expression language.... Is it similar to expression for JSF?

Comment: EL is an standalone API which JSF happens to use. So EL is just EL.